# A clock program in MIPS assembly that start ticking from 59:58

Tags: homework, timer, assembly

This is an assignment, a clock program which use MARS simulator, it starts ticking from `59:58`. In this assignment I have implemented three functions `hexasc`,`time2string` and `delay` ,the other part of the code was given within the assignment which is also in the public domain.

In order to understand and learn more from this assignment I would appreciate to see any different idea, approach and optimization.

> **Some output:**
>
> I'm a clock
>
> 59:58
>
> 59:59
>
> 00:00
>
> 00:01
>
> 00:02
>
> 00:03
>
> 00:04
>
> 00:05

```
.macro  PUSH (%reg)
    addi    $sp,$sp,-4
    sw  %reg,0($sp)
.end_macro

.macro  POP (%reg)
    lw  %reg,0($sp)
    addi    $sp,$sp,4
.end_macro

.data
.align 2
 mytime:    .word 0x5957
 timstr:    .ascii "I'm a clock\0"
.text
 main:
                               # print timstr
        la      $a0,timstr     #load the adress of .ascii
        li      $v0,4          #print string to the Run I/O
        syscall
        nop
                                # wait a little
        li      $a0,300000      #argument to delay (initialy was set to 2)
        jal     delay
        nop
                                # call tick
        la      $a0,mytime      #load the adress of .word the time
        jal     tick
        nop
                                # call your function time2string
        la      $a0,timstr      #load the adress of .ascii again
        la      $t0,mytime      #load the adress of .word again this time in t0
        lw      $a1,0($t0)      #load the adress contained in $t0 into $a1
        jal     time2string
        nop
                                # print a newline
        li      $a0,10
        li      $v0,11
        syscall
        nop
                                # go back and do it all again
        j       main
        nop
                            # tick: update time pointed to by $a0
tick:   lw      $t0,0($a0)  # get time
        addiu   $t0,$t0,1   # increase
        andi    $t1,$t0,0xf # check lowest digit
        sltiu   $t2,$t1,0xa # if digit < a, okay
        bnez    $t2,tiend
        nop
        addiu   $t0,$t0,0x6     # adjust lowest digit
        andi    $t1,$t0,0xf0    # check next digit
        sltiu   $t2,$t1,0x60    # if digit < 6, okay
        bnez    $t2,tiend
        nop
        addiu   $t0,$t0,0xa0    # adjust digit
        andi    $t1,$t0,0xf00   # check minute digit
        sltiu   $t2,$t1,0xa00   # if digit < a, okay
        bnez    $t2,tiend
        nop
        addiu   $t0,$t0,0x600   # adjust digit
        andi    $t1,$t0,0xf000  # check last digit
        sltiu   $t2,$t1,0x6000  # if digit < 6, okay
        bnez    $t2,tiend
        nop
        addiu   $t0,$t0,0xa000  # adjust last digit
tiend:  sw      $t0,0($a0)  # save updated result
        jr      $ra         # return
        nop

        # you can write your code for subroutine "hexasc" and  below this line
hexasc:
        andi    $a0,$a0,0xf     #only 4 least significant bits ignore(clear) other bits
        addi    $v0,$zero,0x30  #$v0 = 0x30 ('0' ASCII character)
        addi    $t0,$zero,0x9   #t0 = 0x9

        ble     $a0,$t0,L1      #branch to L1 if a0 <= t0
        nop
        addi    $v0,$v0,0x7     #v0 = v0 +0x7 (thier is 7 other characters from 0x39 to 0x41) thats why
        #0x7 is added to the v0 to ignore the gap and jump directly to 'A' in ASCII table

L1:
        add     $v0,$a0,$v0     #v0 = V0 +a0
        jr      $ra
        nop


delay:
        PUSH    ($s0)
        PUSH    ($ra)
        addi    $s0, $0,1000    #i = 0
        addi    $t1,$0,30000    #(intitaly was t1=4711)
        move    $t0,$a0     #move the argument to t0
while:
        ble     $t0,$s0,done    #branch to done if ms > 0
        nop
        addi    $t0,$t0,-1      #decrement ms by 1
for:
        beq     $s0,$t1,done2
        nop
        addi    $s0,$s0,1
        j       for
done2:

        j       while
done:
        POP     ($ra)
        POP     ($s0)
        jr      $ra
        nop



time2string:
        PUSH    ($s0)
        PUSH    ($s1)
        PUSH    ($ra)       #nested subroutine must store $ra too

        add     $s0,$0,$a0      #contains the address of string (timstr)
        add     $s1,$0,$a1      #contains the time-info(0x5957)

        andi    $t0,$s1,0xf000      #check the 4 most significant bits ignore(clear) other bits
        srl     $a0,$t0,12      #shift the MSB to LSB position (hexasc take only 4 bits in the LSB position)
        jal     hexasc      # call hexasc
        nop
        sb      $v0, 0($s0)     #store that 4 bits in that location that a0 points to

        andi    $t1,$s1,0x0f00  #mask to get those 4 bits you need and ignore other bits
        srl     $a0,$t1,8       #shift those bits to the LSB position(0x000f)
        jal     hexasc      #this is because hexasc only take argument on the LSB position and clear other bits.
        nop
        sb      $v0,1($s0)      #store this bits in that address pointed by a0

        li      $t3,0x3A        #t3 = a colon in ASCII table
        sb      $t3,2($s0)


        andi    $t2,$s1,0x00f0
        srl     $a0,$t2,4
        jal     hexasc
        nop
        sb      $v0,3($s0)


        move    $a0,$s1
        jal     hexasc
        nop
        sb      $v0, 4($s0)


        li      $t4,0x00        # a null \0 in ASCII table
        sb      $t4,5($s0)


        POP     ($ra)
        POP     ($s1)
        POP     ($s0)

        jr       $ra
        nop
```